# Flutter Drawer clipBehaviour isn't working correctly

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation-drawer

I'm trying not to clip the `Drawer` edges, I used `clipBehavior: Clip.none` but it only affects the upper corner. Like so,

[image: drawer screenshot]

What would be a quick fix for this? Here's the code to regenerate issue:

```
Scaffold(
      endDrawer: Drawer(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        elevation: 0,
        child: ListView(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Image.asset('assets/images/ULesson.png'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('My Courses'),
              onTap: () {
                // TODO: Handle My Courses menu item tap
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('My Quizes'),
              onTap: () {
                // TODO: Handle My Quizes menu item tap
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Live Classes'),
              onTap: () {
                // TODO: Handle Live Classes menu item tap
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Notification Setup'),
              onTap: () {
                // TODO: Handle Notification Setup menu item tap
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Certificate'),
              onTap: () {
                // TODO: Handle Certificate menu item tap
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Purchase History'),
              onTap: () {
                // TODO: Handle Purchase History menu item tap
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('My Profile'),
              onTap: () {
                // TODO: Handle My Profile menu item tap
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Account Settings'),
              onTap: () {
                // TODO: Handle Account Settings menu item tap
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Deposit'),
              onTap: () {
                // TODO: Handle Deposit menu item tap
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Reward Point'),
              onTap: () {
                // TODO: Handle Reward Point menu item tap
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Logged In Devices'),
              onTap: () {
                // TODO: Handle Logged In Devices menu item tap
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Referral'),
              onTap: () {
                // TODO: Handle Referral menu item tap
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```